# Solving Pretty Permalinks on Local Server on WAMP - Modrewrite ok, followsymlinks ok, Override ok. Still doesn't work

Tags: wordpress, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I've fought this for years and today I want to see if I can finally make the magic happen. I set pretty permalinks in my options and it creates the following in my .htaccess file:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
# BEGIN WordPress
#<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /nameofsite/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /nameofsite/index.php [L]
#</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

The followsymlinks line is something I added based on advice from another thread.

In my Apache.conf file, I HAVE uncommented mod_rewrite, I changed all lines from Allowoverride none to ALL. I changed all require all denied to GRANTED. Order deny,allow is now ALLOW,DENY. Allow from ALL... I've unlocked the crap out of my server because it's just on my computer and I'm more interested in making permalinks work properly.

The result of this effort: a webpage containing only the following code (according to the document inspector):

```
<html><head></head><body></body></html>
```

No errors, just blankness.

If leave a spelling error in the .htaccess file, it gives a 500 server error so I know it's reading and reacting to the file. I've most definitely restarted the Apache server after every change. Other relevant information:

- My server is not localhost/ it's localhost/nameofsite
- I used Bitnami to install the WAMP stack, but my htdocs folder is in a custom location. I've uncommented all lines in my httpd.conf file that point to bitnami configuration files to make sure they're not a problem.

It seems like there must be SOMETHING wrong and I'm tired of reading all the other articles that say "thanks that worked" for basic configuration problems that I've long since corrected. Nothing seems to cover what to do when you get a completely blank page.

Answer (score 0):

I realized that there's only one reason why I'd get a totally blank page.

I changed @ini_set('display_errors','Off'); in my wp-config.php file to ON and apparently changing to pretty permalinks loaded some other file or addon that wasn't there before and one of the function names was conflicting with one of mine. Once I was able to see the error and changed the name of my function, pretty permalinks WORKS for the FIRST TIME IN THE YEARS I'VE TRIED.

If you do the same, be sure to turn off display errors when you're done or do what I did and have a code fork for the database variables and other settings depending on whether you're local or on your live server.